# Subset of mutually exclusive items from sets

Tags: algorithm, set

I have sets `S_0, ..., S_N`. How do I find the largest subset `T`, such that the intersection `I_i` of `T` and `S_i` (for each 0 <= `i` <= N) contains at most one element.

I have a solution for this, but I'm guessing that it's unnecessarily slow (essentially several nested for-loops trying out all combinations). So my question is:

- Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?
- If not, is there an efficient algorithm that finds *large* subsets `T`?

Comment: By `S_n`, do you mean `S_N` or `S_n`, for each `0 <= n <= N`? Can you give an example so we can be sure we understand the problem correctly?

Comment: I mean S_n. I'l update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are unlikely to find an efficient general algorithm for this problem because I believe it is NP complete.

If you had an efficient algorithm to solve this, then you could solve the [maximum independent set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29#Finding_maximum_independent_sets).

### Sketch of Proof

Suppose you have a graph, then for each edge construct a set containing {i,j} where i and j are the vertices connected by the edge.

Then the largest subset T for these sets will be the maximal independent set for your graph.

### Conversion to Maximal independent set

More usefully, you can also express your problem in terms of finding a maximal independent set for the graph where there is an edge between a and b if and only if there is a set that contains both a and b.

You may then be able to use some standard solvers for the maximal independent set problem such as the [one in Pythons NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.mis.maximal_independent_set.html#networkx.algorithms.mis.maximal_independent_set).

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up your program by caching whether the intersection of sets `S_a` and `S_b` are empty or not. Rather than building the set `T` which I think is the union of some of the sets in `S`. You keep a list `T` of the indexes of sets and to check if a set `S_n` intersects with `T` you check if in the table for the set in `T` that `S_n` intersects with one of them.

I did this in one of my Python programs as the set intersection test was the slow spot.